# Input with type date dont work in safari any alternative for angular?

Tags: angular, angular9

I did some research and found that the safari does not support the `type="date"` for an alternative date using jquery apparently made it work or datepicker in some way to do this in the angular in a more natural way?

my input

```
<input
    [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }"
    [ngModel]="user.expirationDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'"
    (ngModelChange)="user.expirationDate = $event"
    (blur)="save()"
    type="date"
    class="form-control"
/>
```

alternative working with Jquery

```
<input type="date" id="test" />
```

Js

```
if ( $('#test')[0].type != 'date' ) $('#test').datepicker();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery UI datepicker is obsolete and ends up with serious UI issues on Safari as well. (Which I ended up fixing by adding clumsy text-indent hack)
I Would recommend Angular material datepicker
https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview